# WordPress authentication in xamarin forms

Tags: wordpress, xamarin.forms

I am making a phone app where a user can log themselves in with the username and password they use on a WordPress site. Right now I am doing this using JSON API User plugin. I send a simple http get request to the URL https://domain/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?email=EMAIL&password=PASSWORD. This returns a cookie which I can then use to send another get https request to get said user ID. Right now this works because I am using a staging environment where security is less of a concern. However I'm not sure how safe this is as I am sending the email and password of users as plain text. Is this a safe way of authenticating users? And if its not what other ways of authentication should I look into?

Comment: Even if you are using https that is kind of secure, you can always add some more security. For example you can send the email/password using some kind of hash (but you will have to use the same hash on the server). Algo I guess you could use some kind oAuth, but I can't help you much with it

Comment: WordPress hashes the passwords itself, so there is no way of getting the same hash as the server does.

Comment: I don't think there is much choice if you are using a JSON. On the [Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) site it says that there are some other ways of doing that. Maybe you could try that